# cocos2d-js, is there a way to stop cc.game and rebind it to another canvas and then restart the game?

Tags: cocos2d-js

I try to have a canvas inside a query mobile page, first time it runs well, but when I switch to another page and removed the page containing canvas from the dom, and switch back again, I try to setup the game once more, it didn't work

how to end the cc.game properly so I can reconfigure it again?